# How do I display an animated image during Page Load using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, animation, load

I have an ASP.NET page that takes a long time to load due to the loading of multiple user controls. Is there a way where I can show a loading animation using jQuery while the page is loading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

simply insert a div as absolute position and style it as you want , when page is loaded hide it ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<style>
.boxMid{position:absolute; top:30%; left:40%; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:#fff;
               border:1px solid #333; display:block;}
#mybox{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#666666; opacity:.8; display:block;filter:alpha(opacity=80);}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mybox" >
    <div class="boxMid">
     Loading, please wait ...
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="loading">loading</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).load(function(){
        $('#mybox').fadeOut();
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi there, can you please elaborate? I'm a newbie to jQuery development :( Whats happening is that the image is not displaying during the page loading but rather only after it. I need the image to display during the loading of the page.

Thanks!

Comment: i update the replay , just add content and your jquery path instead of `src="jq.js"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery.

You can simply add an `<img>` tag displaying an animated GIF.
You can find a suitable animated GIF at [AJAXLoad.info](http://ajaxload.info).

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I use [BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block) for jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

```
   $.ajaxSetup({   
      beforeSend:function(){   
         $("#loading").show();   
      },   
      complete:function(){   
         $("#loading").hide();   
   });
```

This will change your global ajax settings to show/hide #loading object while a ajax is being processed.